# Setting Connection Timeout Parameter in postgresql PDO connection

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework, pdo

For some reason I want to set the postgresql connection timeout to 5 sec. I am using the Zend Framework 1.12, And for creating the postgresql connection I am using the **Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql** class, I did not found any parameter by which we can define the connection timeout.

I search around but did not got anything for it. Please give me some suggestion how can I do it.

Thank You

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution: You need to set a timeout before each query:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->query('SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 2000'); //2 Sek. Timeout
$res = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

This only affects the NEXT Query to the DB and it's imporant that you have a Transaction. Without Transaction it won't work.
If you made another Query after it (catch the timeout, rollback transaction), it will still have the default TIMEOUT.
Creating a DB Routine will not work! You really have to set the timeout in your Function.